# Should large data files be kept in a docker conatiner?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I have an application that serves as a simple lookup service for structured data. The data has to be imported via an API after the service starts and is not being persisted, meaning it has to be re-imported after every restart of the service. I want to run the service in a docker environment.

My approach to making the service "up and running" in one single deploy command is to copy the data into a docker container with the service and have a shell script as an entry point which starts the service and then fills it with the data (found this pattern [here](https://success.docker.com/article/use-a-script-to-initialize-stateful-container-data)). That way the service is ready to use right after deployment without having to import the data manually.

The data can, however, be fairly large for program data (approximately up to 1GB), which makes the container image per se quite large. I am quite new to docker, so is there any negative side effect this might have? It seems to work fine for now, but maybe there is some downside I don't see yet.

Answer (score 0):

Docker images are built in layers. So if your file/dir doesn't change docker just re-uses the layer while building the container image.

1. If the data you are using in the docker application doesn't change frequently you can keep part of the docker container.
2. Mount the file(s)/directory while starting the container using -v option